# What does" .class expected error " mean in java

Tags: java

Here is my code. I got an error as ".class expected".
What should I do to rectify it.

```
import java.util.*;
class Atm2
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount to be withdrawed");
        int withdraw = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the amount in the account");
        double acnt_balc = in.nextDouble();
        if ((withdraw % 5 == 0) && (acnt_balc >= withdraw + 0.50))
            double cur = acnt_balc - (withdraw + 0.50);
            System.out.println(cur);
        else
            System.out.println(acnt_balc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` presumably needs brackets `{}`.

Comment: *Where* is the error? Please try harder to format your code nicely in future - it's really hard to read at the moment. Use the preview before you post.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you try to run the code? Did you compile it first? Did you remember to reference it by class name not file name when running?

`javac Atm2.java`
`java Atm2`

Comment: A dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809878/what-does-error-class-expected-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

Try curly braces in the context of your if-else.
It should look like this:

```
if (isMoving) {
    currentSpeed--;
} else {
    System.err.println("The bicycle has already stopped!");
}
```

So you can see, that there is a if-block and a else-block. You have to say which code belongs to if and which belongs to else. You can do that with the braces.

Answer (score -1):

Scanner requires you to import java.util.*;

I tried it works and also format properly , see below , it runs

```
import java.util.*;

    class Atm2

        {
            public static void main (String args[])
            {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the amount to be withdrawed");
                int withdraw = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the amount in the account");
                double acnt_balc = in.nextDouble();
                if ((withdraw % 5 == 0) && (acnt_balc >=(withdraw + 0.50)))
                {
                 double cur=(acnt_balc-(withdraw + 0.50));
                    System.out.println(cur);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(acnt_balc);
                }
            }
        }
```

Also make sure your Filename is the same as class name , in this case Atm2.java

The Scanner Class in present in the 'java.util' package , since you forgot to import it and used Scanner sc=new Scanner(); the compliler is complaining, and remember to compile use javac filename.java , to run use java filename

Comment: Sorry I edited it out, see http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26437719/2

Comment: @msrd0 ,Please include your corrections as a reply ,if you edit it to make it correct, others viewing the post may not understand the problem and learn from it

Comment: No, while formatting the code I removed the `import` statement without noting that. I now added it again, but the OP had it before

Comment: Oops Alright , new to edits ,didnt notice , sorry.